# That doesn't necessarily mean acceptance of the contract from your "part" or "side"?

Tags: differences

**A)**

> Your engagement in these practices doesn't necessarily mean acceptance of the contract from your ***side***.

**B)**

> Your engagement in these practices doesn't necessarily mean acceptance of the contract from your ***part***.

Are the two sentences equivalent?. If not, which one is the correct within the context?

Comment: There is no "context" here. We have two sentences divorced from any context.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I updated the two sentences :)